# sample pandas, keeping collected records together

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to (approximately) partition a large number of records in a dataframe.  This is easily achieved using `sample`:

```
fraction = .7
df1     = df.sample(frac = fraction)
df2     = df.drop(df1.index)
```

Now for my question: Suppose I'd like to (randomly) partition the dataset but must also keep all records of a `group` together.  It can be assumed that only a few records belong to each group, so that it will not interfere with the ability to randomly partition.  An example, noting that the `group` only collects a few records and therefore does not impose significant constraint:

```
df = 
      group   value
0     'aaa'    48
1     'aaa'   -103
2     'aab'    20     
3     'aac'    21
4     'aac'    40
...
10000 'zzf'    220
```

Comment: Why not resample and then sort on `group no`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm not sure I follow.  In any case I don't have a time-like index, and I would like random sampling.  Do you have a solution in mind?

Comment: I'm thinking... but it's hard to visualise a solution without seeing some sort of data. Could you, perhaps, provide a sample input and output? It would help tbh.

Comment: Can you try groupby and then sample the groups as:                         grouped = df.groupby('group')
grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.7))

Answer (score 0):

Can you try groupby and then sample the groups as:

```
grouped = df.groupby('group') 
grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=0.7)) –
```

Comment: Does this sample each subgroup, taking f=0.7?  That's the opposite of what I want.  I want each subgroup to be in *either* one group, or *another*.